# Ayuda con Redireccion desde HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, http, apache2, redirección, https

me ocupa lo siguiente, poseo el siguiente código en mi archivo HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.miweb.com.ve [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www.miweb.com.ve$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://miweb.com.ve/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Desde mi servidor de DNS las peticiones tanto a `miweb.com.ve` como `www.miweb.com.ve` apuntan a la misma IP.

Una vez en mi server la respuesta ejecutada es bajo un certificado SSL y requiero que las peticiones sean entonces tratadas como https, eso lo he configurado desde mi apache adecuando la respuesta desde el virtualhost *.80 de la siguiente manera:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName miweb.com.ve
        ServerAlias miweb.com.ve
        ServerAdmin info@miweb.com.ve
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</VirtualHost>
```

**LO QUE HACE COMO ESTA**

Así como actualmente esta configurado si hago la petición a `https://miweb.com.ve` mi web funciona perfectamente, pero si la petición es desde `www.miweb.com.ve` o desde `https://www.miweb.com.ve` da error de uso de certificado, por ello lo que pretendo es que si alguien hace una petición desde el sitio con www o sin www en http o si la petición es bajo https a la web con www todo sea redireccionado al dominio simple **miweb.com.ve**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que para lo que pides necesitas algo así en tu fichero `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Fuente original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47890904/1552146

Aunque, por lo que comentas, creo que tu problema sobre certificados no es a causa de tu configuración del fichero `.htaccess`, sino por tu certificado como tal. Si `https://tudominio.ltd` funciona, es decir, que tu navegador responde con "candado verde" y, en cambio, `https://anysubdomain.tudominio.ltd` devuelve error, es decir, "candado rojo", es que tu certificado está firmado únicamente para tu dominio pero no para los subdominios.

Para arreglar esta parte, necesitarías lo que se conoce como `wildcard certificate`. Un certificado que cubra todos los subdominios, es decir, que cualquier subdominio existente de tu dominio esté securizado: `https://*.tudominio.ltd`